# CodeIgniter Access Controller based on Role

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this CodeIgniter Controller and I simply trying that if a user has role 1 or two, he can access this Controller otherwise it will redirect it but its not working. Please Hlep.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Users extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('my_helper');   
        $userAdmin=$this->session->userdata('_manage');
        if($userAdmin==false){
            redirect(base_url()."manage/index");
            exit();
        }
        $userRole=$this->session->userdata('_manage_role');
        if($userRole != 1 || $userRole != 2){
            redirect(base_url()."manage/index");
            exit();
        }
        $this->load->model('UserModel');        
    }
    // Manage Section > All Users Pagse > All Users
    public function index()
    {
        $Users  = $this->UserModel->allUsers();     
        $assignData=array('users'=>$Users);
        $this->load->view('manage/header',$assignData);
        $this->load->view('manage/users');
        $this->load->view('manage/footer');     
    }
    public function deleteUser($user_id)
    {
        $this->userModel->deleteUser($user_id);
        redirect(base_url().'manage/users');
    }   
}
```

Comment: What is the current outcome?

Comment: it doesn't works, If a user has role one or user b has role two, it redirect to index page. I need to check if a user coming from role one OR (||) role two , he / she can access the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this line:

```
if($userRole != 1 || $userRole != 2) { redirect(...) }
```

to be

```
if($userRole != 1 && $userRole != 2) { redirect(...) }
```

If you split the || test into two if's, it becomes:

```
if ($userRole != 1) { redirect(...) }
if ($userRole != 2) { redirect(...) }
```

If $userRole = 1, it fails the first if. If $userRole = 2 it fails the second if. So there's no way past for either.

Comment: Hi, can you please explain? it works but I have users with either role 1 or role 2. Thank you

Comment: @RizwanRanjha Edited answer.